# Comic story about a pilot who merged with his plane in a crash and became able to fly - sort of!

Tags: story-identification, comics, 2000ad

I remember some elements of this story, but the name and fine details I have forgotten.
It was either in *2000 AD* or *Starlord* comics back in the 80’s in the UK.
If anyone remembers, or can point me at a site with this on, then it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is, I believe, Harry Angel from *2000 AD*. He was an RAF officer involved in a plane crash during which the flight computer of his plane (I thought it was a Harrier (as a play on 'Harry') but [this link](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/harry-angel/4005-83217/) suggests it was a fictional F-20) got bonded to his body, giving him the ability to fly. (Probably you shouldn't overthink how that might work...)

There's a little more detail at the [Fandom page for Harry Angel](https://britishcomics.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Angel).

Comment: Perfect.  Thats the one.

Answer (score 4):

This is a stretch (and I don't know about the comic) but there is a 1973 story by Theodore R. Cogswell and Theodore L. Thomas called [Early Bird](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81635).  In this story, a space "scout"-fighter pilot is in combat over a world populated by cybernetic organisms.  This scout-fighter and pilot end up acting as a sperm and fertilizing an cyber-egg inside a giant cybernetic organism by crashing into it. When the egg hatches, the pilot, scout-fighter, and material from the cybernetic organism are all merged together into a much improved team.

This story is an very inferior (IMHO) sequel to the very good 1952 story [The Spectre General](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55952).

Comment: Sorry, that wasnt the one i was thinking of, but it seems close.  Thanks anyway.